# Sqoop query failed to import: parameter 'directory' is not a directory

Tags: import, sqoop

I am running sqoop - import command via Java but getting an error

> failed to import: parameter directory is not a directory

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace. Are you using --target-dir parameter in sqoop? If yes please check the parameter value you passed is directory or not?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the directory path in --target-dir parameter.

Thanks